# Convex quadrilaterals and Tangents

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line

Given a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, we neeed to prove that the circles inscribed in the triangles $ABC$ and $CDA$ are tangent if and only if  the circles inscribed in the triangles $BCD$ and $DAB$ are tangent.

[image]

Any hints

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the incircles of $ABC$  and $CDA$ are tangent at a  common point on the diagonal $AC$ then $ABCD$ has an incircle. Then look at the diagonal $BD$ and denote the points of tangency of the incircles $ABD$ and $BCD$ with the diagonal $BD$ by $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. Then show that $BQ_1 =  BQ_2$ which is equivalent to $Q_1 \equiv Q_2 \equiv Q$.